# all values X axis histogram SAGE

Tags: sage

I want to plot an histogram in SAGE from a list, my_data, but I want to plot all values of the axis X, in the below example this must be X=[0,1,2,3] but I get 2,4,6,8,10,.... Could you help me please?

```
my_data = [0,1,2,10]
BC=bar_chart(my_data, width=1, color="lightblue", figsize=4)
show(BC,xmin=0,xmax=10)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but take a look here: http://sage.math.canterbury.ac.nz/home/pub/255/ : maybe you'll find some hints (particularly the last chart, is looking good). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), `bar_chart` is a wrong tool for the job. Use [`plot_histogram`](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/prep/Quickstarts/Statistics-and-Distributions.html#distributions) instead. It applies to a [Time Series](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/finance/sage/finance/time_series.html) object, so the data has to be converted to it first.

Examples (with a richer data set, so multiple items sometimes fall into one bin):

```
my_data = [0,1,2,5,3,2,3,8,2,10]
stats.TimeSeries(my_data).plot_histogram(normalize=False,bins=10)
```

Here `normalize=False` means the height of each bar is the raw count.

[image: histogram1]

Change to `normalize=True` to get a histogram where the total area of rectangles is 1, like in a probability distribution.

[image: histogram2]